# Radial menu in Android

Tags: android, popupmenu, radial

Been thinking about adding a radial menu to my app. When the user clicks the button a radial menu appears "around" the button.

Been googling around but cannot find any good examples.

Not looking for a solution, just some hints on where to start. Is a custom view the way to go and draw everything ? Or is there some built-in feature I can look at ?

Comment: You want something like the contextual menu of the Pinterest app ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. At the bottom of the screen I've added a floatbutton, the idea was when this was pressed an radial menu appeared "surrounding" this one. Been playing around a bit now and got into custom view with an override on the onDraw, guessing this might be the way to do..